# Java object serialization for logging

Tags: java, json, serialization

I have been using [ReflectionToStringBuilder](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/apidocs/org/apache/commons/lang3/builder/ReflectionToStringBuilder.html) for serializing object for logging purpose.But we have experienced issue where it does not print full objects. Like for following case

```
GetTimeBlocksOutput tbout = new GetTimeBlocksOutput();
TimeBlock tb = new TimeBlock();
tb.setAvailable(true);
List<TimeBlock> tbList = new ArrayList<TimeBlock>();
tbList.add(tb);
tbout.setTimeBlocks(tbList);
System.out.println(ReflectionToStringBuilder.toString(tbout));
```

It prints

```
mycomp.GetTimeBlocksOutput@55d56113[timeBlocks [mycomp.TimeBlock@2]]
```

Is there a easy way to have serialized object for logging purpose ? mainly something out of box without requiring manual change in object to be printed

[Json serializers](http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-do-convert-java-object-to-from-json-format-gson-api/) are one option but

- should they be used for such cases ?
- Considering Json serialization can throw exception. Is their an easy library that gives simple util method to achieve the task ?

Comment: What is the reason why .toString() override is not practical?

Comment: @Compass can't tell without more details from OP, but it's possible that they don't have the ability to modify the class in question.

Comment: @avojak if that is the issue, then I'd think a helper method that runs all the public gets into a String would be a more viable option. Using reflection to get logging out of a closed class is a bandaid.

Comment: @Compass I agree - and not only a bandaid, but very brittle as well. I was just addressing a scenario where simply overriding isn't viable :)

Comment: Sorry for delayed response.
Class in question is coming from library like input/output classes for service call or entity bean class to represent object in persistent layer 
Writing helper method tightly couple your code with underline entity. What if some one added another property to the bean, you logs would not have this additional field. You will not realize missing info until something fail in production and you want to know what were the values for the properties of object.
If there are alternative ways available, then we should not be maintaining unnecessary code.

Answer (score 3):

What you are seeing is the default `toString()` implementation.

From `Object.java`

```
public String toString() {
    return getClass().getName() + "@" + Integer.toHexString(hashCode());
}
```

Simply override this method and return a `String` representation that suits your needs!

GetTimeBlocksOutput could be

```
public String toString() {
    return this.timeBlocks.toString(); // assuming timeBlocks can't be null
}
```

TimeBlock could be

```
public String toString() {
    return "Available:" + this.available;
}
```

You haven't shared much about the information contained in TimeBlock and GetTimeBlocksOutput but I'm sure you can come up with a good implementation.

Comment: Thats the way to go if you control the implementation of the class. But what if class can not be modified as it is coming from library.

Comment: @SameerChaudhary You could simply create a `TimeBlockUtils` which would contain a static `toString(GetTimeBlocksOutput)` method in which you'd do something very similar. There's no need to use reflection here.

Comment: Please refer my response here 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37555791/java-object-serialization-for-logging#comment63107108_37555791